# unknown tag name in file commons-lang3/ivy-3.4.xml.original

Tags: sbt, ivy, sbt-docker

I am trying to use `commons-lang3` and I am getting error as

`unknown tag name in file:/Users/myuser/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/ivy-3.4.xml.original`

I tried to exclude the dependency but it is needed to do the parsing of docker file.

Do you know how can i fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't appear to be an ivy issue. The following dependency <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.4" Resolved without issue

Answer (score 2):

I had to clear wipe of the ivy cache and then it worked